Displaying the Footnoterule and Footnotes Farther Up the Page (One Time)
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\LARGE
This is a sentence.\footnote{I would like to be able to move this footnote and the footnoterule line farther up the page---this one time. The rest of pages (if there were any) would display footnotes in the usual manner.}
\end{document}

with the output:

QUESTION: How may I, on an ad hoc basis, shift the footnoterule and its associated footnote upwards on the page so that the lower portion (half) of the page is kept free for another purpose? In a real document, I might do this only once---with all other pages containing footnotes displaying them in the usual manner.
Thank you.

What is the other purpose? To do this properly would be non-trivial. I suspect it might be very non-trivial. To fake it, on the other hand, might be very doable, depending on what you want to do with the rest of the page.

@cfr I would like the publisher's name and address to appear with its logo at the bottom of a particular page in a book. I figured it might be bad typography to have a footnote appear below this information. The footnote is needed though, on that page.

This is slightly fiddly, but it should work and is probably a bit cleaner than just adding space into the footnote.
We do a manual adjustment using \changetext{}{}{}{}{} from changepage before including the footnote. We add the logo or whatever to the shipout/background hook for the page. Then we \clearpage and use \changetext in reverse.
If the end of a paragraph begins the page, it should not be too long, and \changetext should be issued immediately after the paragraph break. Otherwise, the command should be given immediately at the start of the page.
If the page is odd, \oddsidemargin should be substituted for \evensidemargin. This is probably obvious, but the code does nothing to evaluate which kind of page it is on. If you want to position the additional material relative to the physical page, rather than the text block, this won't be a problem as you won't need this kind of calculation.
Inside the shipout hook, remember that \textheight is reduced by the relevant amount. (This is ... er ... possible to forget and ... er ... might be confusing.)
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}%
\kant[1-4]

\changetext{-275pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}%
\AddToHookNext{shipout/foreground}{%
  \put (25.4mm+\evensidemargin,-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-2.54cm-\textheight-137.5pt)
  {%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \Huge LOGO \& NAME
      \par
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
}%
{\LARGE
  This is a sentence.\footnote{I would like to be able to move this footnote and the footnoterule line farther up the page---this one time. The rest of pages (if there were any) would display footnotes in the usual manner.}\par}

\clearpage
\changetext{275pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}%
\kant[5-10]
\end{document}


In light of the comment of cfr, I figured I would post a makeshift solution.
However, I would like to see this done a better way.
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
This is a sentence.\footnotemark

\footnotesize \vspace*{135pt} \moveleft-15pt\vbox{\footnoterule}
%\footnote{A good vertical distance} 
\vbox{\footnote[1] \, The footnote.}
\end{document}

which produces the acceptable output:

